# Собственная библиотека при веб-разработке

Tags: веб-программирование, frontend, бэм

Занимаясь верстанием сайтов сталкиваюсь с тем, что код некоторых компонентов на процентов 90 идентичен. Выходит, что я трачу время на написание почти того же кода, который писал ранее. Не вижу в этом целесообразности. Закономерно может придти решение - пользуйся Bootstrap`ом или его аналогом. Считаю, что современному веб-разработчику он обязателен для понимания. Вместе с тем готовые фреймворки и библиотеки не являются "выстраданными": их не понимаешь изнутри, нужно потратить время на их изучение, что-то тебе не понравится, что-то не поймёшь и т.д.

В такой ситуации, как я вижу, самое подходящее решение - это создание собственной библиотеки, код которой будет потом вставляться в нужные места и просто адаптироваться.

Поэтому возникают следующие вопросы:

1. Где есть более подробная информация по этой теме?
2. Какими ключевыми словами можно самостоятельно найти информацию в интернете?
3. Как вы, господа, пользуетесь **своими библиотеками**? Если да, то как создаёте, организуете, пополняете и т.д.?
4. И какие рекомендации могут подкинуть те, кто глубоко владеет BEM(БЭМ)?

Comment: Обижусь, если не обоснуешь по какой причине вопрос глупый.

Comment: Ну раз ты не  первый день  верстаешь, ты и так знаешь ответ...  Потому и глупый...   А  интересный, потому, что идея не нова, но гениальна...

Comment: Что именно непонятно при создании своей библиотеки для использования? Все просто же, потрать 2-3 дня на ее создание и сэкономь много времени в будущем

Comment: Просто создай файл css и сделай себе правилом, какие селекторы как называть...  Уверен у тебя уже есть какие-то наработанные правила... И утебя будет свой собственный бутстрап))))))

Comment: Могу допустить, что, с твоей точки зрения, у каждого более-менее опытного веб-разработчика уже есть собственная библиотека. И видимо, с твоей т.з., создание библиотеки под себя  - это настолько очевидное решение, что оно даже не потребует какого-либо обсуждения. Верно?

Comment: Я верстаю 5 год...  Ни разу не  воспользовался ни одной библиотекой...   У меня есть своя)))  Но она у меня в голове...

Comment: @Air, то есть с нуля каждый раз пишешь код?

Comment: Да... Я такой ленивый, что до библиотеки руки не доходят...

Comment: @Alexxosipov, а допустим, с позиции БЭМ-методологии как организовывать свою библиотеку?

Comment: В смысле как? Если знаешь БЭМ методологию, то это глупый вопрос, а если не знаешь, то учи, если хочешь по ней все делать. Либо же я тебя не понял, задай конкретнее вопрос